# Positioning of elements in a horizontal timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a custom timeline feature but I'm stuck on how to solve a certain positioning I want in edge-cases.

In the snippet below I have 3 timelines for demonstration:

- The first is a timeline with many events. The timeline is supposed overflow the ones that don't fit. This is determined by a given `min-width` for `li`.
- The second and third have few events. The positioning here needs to be so that they are equally spaced between eachother.

I also want the first and last events to be pulled to the left and right respectively, instead of centered.

#### What I have so far:

The width of each item is calculated based on the number of events. The `min-width` property prevents the size getting too small. The overflow is intended.

I thought I'd fix the spacing issue on the first and last event by pulling them left and right with `left/right: XX %` but the elements seem to behave as if they are positioned absolutely. I also tried `float` as well as using a fixed width and controlling the width by `margin` but that didn't work either.

```css
.timeline-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.timeline-container ol {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 30px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #EEE;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline-container ol li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 9px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.timeline-container ol li:before {
  content: "";
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #3598DC;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
.timeline-container ol li a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-container">
  <ol>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 8</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 9</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 11</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 13</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 17</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 18</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 19</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 21</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 22</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 26</a></li>
    <li style="width: 9.09091%;"><a>Feb 28</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="timeline-container">
  <ol>
    <li style="width: 50%;"><a>Feb 8</a></li>
    <li style="width: 50%;"><a>Feb 28</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div class="timeline-container">
  <ol>
    <li style="width: 25%;"><a>Feb 8</a></li>
    <li style="width: 25%;"><a>Feb 9</a></li>
    <li style="width: 25%;"><a>Feb 11</a></li>
    <li style="width: 25%;"><a>Feb 13</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

**Desired behavior:** (note the reduced margin left and right margin on the first and last item resp.)

[image]

A pure-css solution that would be preferable, but javascript is fine too. Thanks.

Comment: Personally I would use `flexbox` for this. For timelines with many events, setting them all to have `flex: 1` property will make them automatically be evenly spaced, and for few items, you can use `justify-content: space-between` to have them spaced out as far as possible.

Comment: @Coleman, I still have a slight preference against the use of flexbox due to IE support, but if that's the only viable solution that's absolutely fine. Care to post an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach the design to the post? what about the overflow x no scroll?

Comment: @Chris Sure, I understand. You can help remedy that issue with a CSS autoprefixer. It will add the necessary properties for IE. I'll post an answer as well.

Comment: @Pangloss, what design are you referring to? The overflow hidden is there to disable scrolling. I will later add `<` and `>` buttons to "scroll" with javascript. But that's irrelevant atm. Right now I just want the items to align nicely in every scenario (few or many items).

Comment: It's very hard to know how it should look like, e.g. does the same date in each row need to be aligned vertically?

Comment: @Pangloss There's only one event per day.

Comment: i would use a table, tr for each month, td for each date, alway 31 tds and empty td for day with no event.

Comment: @Pangloss. That doesnt achieve much. Basically same result and problems as I have currently.

Comment: Again you might have different design, but I would do this  https://jsfiddle.net/kc2w5mLd/

Comment: @Pangloss I think you have misunderstood what I want. Like *entirely*.

Comment: Well, good luck then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're alright with using flexbox, it could look something like this:

For many timeline items:

```
<div class="timeline many">
     <div class="timeline__item"></div>
     <div class="timeline__item"></div>
     <div class="timeline__item"></div>
     <div class="timeline__item"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.timeline {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.many .timeline__item {
    flex: 1
}
```

For few items:

```
<div class="timeline few">
         <div class="timeline__item"></div>
         <div class="timeline__item"></div>
         <div class="timeline__item"></div>
         <div class="timeline__item"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.timeline {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.few .timeline__item {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

For IE support you can use a tool like Gulp or Webpack to prefix your styles, or just paste them in an online one here: https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: Havent tested this yet, but looks promising. How would I go about with the styling though? The timeline events are fetched from a server and theres no way I can know beforehand which styling to apply. I cant do any logic like "if more than x items, do... else do.." because this would vary between viewports. :/ Need a more dynamic solution than this.

Comment: Maybe on smaller viewports you can switch to a different kind of view, like a vertical timeline? Something horizontal wouldn't make the most sense on a phone sized screen anyway.